# Code prints back intended result but then adds None. i dont understand why. Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Code:**

```
def isPhoneNumber(text):
    if len(text) == 12:
     print('is 12 characters long')
     
print(isPhoneNumber('415-555-1011'))
```

**Expected Result:**

> is 12 characters long

**Result:**

> is 12 characters long
>
> None

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the result returned by your function.

In python, if a function has no `return` statement, it returns `None` by default.  So when you call your function inside the `print` function, you see the output of the `print` function executed within the function, then the result - `None`.

Answer (score 0):

Do either:

```
def isPhoneNumber(text):
    if len(text) == 12:
        print('is 12 characters long')

isPhoneNumber('415-555-1011')
```

Or:

```
def isPhoneNumber(text):
    if len(text) == 12:
        return 'is 12 characters long'

print(isPhoneNumber('415-555-1011'))
```

In your code, the `isPhoneNumber` method printed the string, but did not return anything. The return value of methods that do not contain a `return` statement is `None`, so the print statement in the last line prints `None` after the print statement in the method printed `is 12 characters long`.

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `print` at the bottom of the code will cause `isPhoneNumer` to call print (which results in the line you expect) and then print the result of calling that function (which, since you didn't specify a return value, is `None`).